# Why can't open some HTML5 video when open `Use hardware acceleration when available`

Tags: html, google-chrome

env:

- Windows 7 32bit
- Chrome v30

Why can't open HTML5 video on some site, such as [xuetangx.com/](http://www.xuetangx.com/) when check the `Use hardware acceleration when available` on Chrome setting?

Is the vedio coding not supported on Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work when that setting is disabled?

Comment: Possibly related to graphics drivers in that case, Chrome can only use what the graphics cards provide. I am surprised there is not a software fallback, it may be worth submitting a bug report to Google.

Comment: @RichieFrame but Chrome play flash video is OK anytime.

Comment: @RichieFrame and Chrome does not prompt any info when can't play some HTML5, just as it is loading video. The only abnormality I can see is the progress bar doesn't move.

Comment: Exactly, the flash plugin handles decode for flash video, but Chrome itself handles the HTML5 video decode unless another plugin has taken over. Is it possible you have another plugin trying to decode the video?

Comment: I'm not sure about this specific situation, but in my experience, using Chrome/Firefox with "try to hardware accelerate" on is quite problematic on "relatively-low end" PCs. It feels like browsers _think_ they can use hardware to help, while in fact they're noticeably lagging. "Definitely-low end" PCs somethings performs better because software fallback triggered (though with some shiny features sacrificed too).

Comment: @RichieFrame Thanks! Maybe my Dell E6400 is the "relatively-low end" is the cause of the phenomenon.

Comment: @RichieFrame Can you give a answer bellow? I'll check.

Comment: I have an E6400, doing a little testing right now, what CPU? I can play 720p HTML5 video no problem.

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU P8700 @ 2.53Hz 2.54Hz, can you play video on http://www.xuetangx.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I am posting an answer now that may help relating to drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that will prevent video from decoding when hardware acceleration is enabled and available; the browser, the graphics driver, or the graphics hardware.

The Browser.
In the case of Chrome, video decoding is either handled by the browser or a plugin. If a plugin is not being used, and the browser fails to decode the video with hardware acceleration, it should fall back into a software decode mode. The P8700 is fully capable of decoding 720p 30fps video in software. The inability to fallback given conditions which prevent hardware acceleration from decoding the video is the most likely cause of this problem. If a plugin has taken over, it can be disabled in the settings menu to allow Chrome to perform the decode.

The Graphics Driver.
With a Dell E6400, you are most likely using an Intel series 4 integrated graphics driver. Intel graphics drivers are updated frequently, but OEMs such as Dell do not release an updated version for download. You must get updates from Intel. Newer drivers may prevent a situation that causes the browser or plugin to fallback to software mode.

[The latest 32-bit driver for the 4-series chipset as of this post](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22165&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20%20%2a&DownloadType=)

The Graphics Hardware.
Intel series 4 integrated graphics support BluRay decode of 1080p video, and as such should not be the weak link here.

Comment: Confused, my Intel series 4 integrated graphics driver is the latest 15.17.19.2869. We have the same hardware and driver, why do I still have the issue?

Comment: It may still be the browser, do you have a link to a specific video?

Comment: Can you open the video on the right on https://www.xuetangx.com/courses/TsinghuaX/TSINGHUA101/_/about , it can't be played with `Use hardware acceleration when available` open on my Chrome v30

Comment: Plays just fine, Chrome 30.0.1599.101m. The only difference between our systems is mine is running win7x64, driver version is the same. CPU usage is only about 30% with hardware accel, 65% without.

Comment: but it can play some other HTML5 video, such as https://class.coursera.org/prob-001/lecture/5

Comment: Can't reach the reason, so I'll close the `Use hardware acceleration when available` temporarily.